# How to do git checkout -q --archive with Python?

Tags: python, git

I'm trying build an code in python using git.Is there any command to do git checkout -q --dir on python?

Now I'm using **Python 3** and **git package** to do this, but i don't found command to this.

I'm running a git pull before (and the command exists), there is a file that can not be deleted and only the git checkout can restore it. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) has neither `--archive` nor `--dir`. Are you looking for `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file`?

Comment: @phd you are right. I'm looking for this!